# Is there any way to update the value of a variable in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a course table which has the course name, course id and price of the course. I also have a discount table which contains the course id and discount applied on the course. I want to write a sql query that is able to return total amount gained. Now, this is calculated by multiplying the number of students enrolled in a course and the price of course. But here, the price of course will change if the user has applied a discount coupon. How can I change the price of course in the query accordingly? 
Currently it is returning the amount gained without considering any discount.

I was thinking of using case statement. Will it work for what I am trying to achieve here?

Here is the SQL query that I am using:

```
SELECT 
    c.course_price * COUNT(e.course_id) AS s
FROM
    EnrolledCourseDetails e,
    Courses c
WHERE
    e.course_id = c.course_id
```

Comment: Please share with sample data in tabular format and expected result set by editing your post.

Comment: Can you share your DB structure?

Comment: You should move from comma joins to explicit joins and should not assume all courses have discounts.

Comment: What does it have to do with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
   (((c.course_price*d.discount_in_percent/100)+(c.course_price)) * COUNT(e.course_id)) AS s
FROM
    EnrolledCourseDetails e inner join
    Courses c on e.course_id = c.course_id, discount d where d.discount_code='example01'

> Try This

Comment: A good answer includes an explanation. Include what have you changed and why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect the discount table by joining them.
You might be able to use the discount value of specific student and course.

SELECT 
    ((c.course_price * COUNT(c.course_id)) - discount) AS s
FROM 
    Courses c 
    left join discount d 
    on c.course_id = d.course_id 
WHERE 
    e.course_id = c.course_id